# Informing mobile app users about discounted subscriptions

Tags: android, ios, mobile-application

What is the best way to inform my mobile app's users that I'm providing a limited-time discount on in-app subscriptions, while still informing them that the discount will end after a month and that renewal will be on the original high price?

I need a way on both Android and iOS apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to acheive them.
You can implement push notifications in your app(Or may be having already) and send notifications to users in current update or next update that will appear showing them the offer.

You can also update the app details- highlighting the feature on the market(Playstore/ iTunes).

Comment: Thanks. I have push notifications implemented. 

Quick question, isn't there a way to provide promo codes that the user can enter when he's prompted to subscribe in-app?

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. I mean using the current version, can't I provide discount promo codes that are recognized by apple (I need this to be handled on Apple's side without changing from my side).

Comment: That is, I need the user to know from apple's store subscription popup that the original price is 6$ but he's getting it discounted for this month for 5 $

Comment: SaryAssad where will the user enter code to skip? So you cannot do it. And please upvote and mark it as answer if it helped you

Comment: No skipping. Just lower price

Comment: But the inapp will not be updated. So better offer a temporary subscription for limited time and in its details write it is discounted. Or update current subscription detail and price and later on again update it to normal price and its information

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept the answer if I don't get answers from other people.